# Continuous map from subset of $\mathcal{C}$ (Cantor) to non-measurable set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, cantor-set, measurable-sets

I've come across the following proposition and its proof.

> Given $f(x)=x+V(x)$, where $V(x)$ is the [Cantor-Vitali function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) on $[0,1]$:
>
> 1. $f(x)$ is an homeomorphism from $[0,1]$ to $[0,2]$.
> 2. $\lambda(f(\mathcal{C}))=1$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure and $\mathcal{C}$ is Cantor set.
> 3. Setting $g=f^{-1}$, there is a measurable set $A\subset[0,1]$ whose preimage under $g$ is non-measurable.

Proof for the first two points is straightforward. About the third one, it says

> $f([0,1]\setminus \mathcal{C})$ is a countable union of disjoint open intervals, hence $f(\mathcal{C})$ is a countable union of disjoint closed intervals $T_j$. There exists a $T_k$ such that $\lambda(T_k)>0$ and, since $T_k$ is a closed interval, there's a non-measurable subset $E\subset T_k$.
>
> Then $A=g(E)\subset\mathcal{C}$ is a measurable set because $\lambda$ is complete and $\lambda(\mathcal{C})=0$.

Although this seems reasonable to me, wouldn't it imply that $g(T_k)\subset \mathcal{C}$? But, being $g$ continuous, it would mean that $\mathcal{C}$ contains an interval, and that's false.

Where am I wrong? Or is the excerpt from the proof incorrect? If so, how would I prove the third point?

Comment: I don't think $f(\mathcal C)$ includes any nondegenerate intervals. To prove item 3, I'd first note that "preimage under $g$" is the same as "image under $f$" and second note that, since $\mathcal C$ has measure $0$, all its subsets are measurable. So it suffices to produce a non-measurable subset of $f(\mathcal C)$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Could you please elaborate your last statement? How is that sufficient to produce a non-measurable subset?

Comment: Sorry. My last sentence was ambiguous. I meant that producing a non-measurable subset of $f(\mathcal C)$ suffices to solve the problem (not that the preceding statements suffice to produce such a set). To actually produce such a set, I'd try a construction like a Bernstein set (though I suspect that there may be an easier way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely correct, for the reason you gave, and the "proof" sketched is false.

What we know is that $f(C)$ is a compact set of positive measure. **And any set of positive measure contains a nonmeasurable subset.** Thus $f(C)$ contains a nonmeasurable set $E.$ Therefore $f^{-1}(E)$ is a subset of $C$ that gets mapped to $E$ by $f.$ Because $\lambda (C)=0$ and $\lambda$ is complete, $f^{-1}(E)$ is measurable. Thus we have found a measurable set that is mapped to a nonmeasurable set via the homeomorphism $f.$